# Change the value of `row`

Tags: python, pandas

```
def multiple_dfs(item, sheets, *args):
    """
    Put multiple dataframes into one xlsx sheet
    """

    writer, row = args[:2]

    response = send_request(item).content
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

    df.to_excel(writer, sheets, startrow=row, index=False)
    row += len(df.index) + 2


def create_and_update_worksheets():
    """
    Add 'Player statistics' if the worksheet is not in file_name. 
    Otherwise, it will update the worksheet itself.
    """

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

    for key, value in worksheets:
    --> row = 0
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            values = value.values()
            for item in values:
    -->         multiple_dfs(item, key, writer, row)
        else:
            multiple_dfs(value, key, writer, row)

    for sheet in writer.sheets.values():
        resize_columns(sheet)

    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

I have two arrows in `create_and_update_worksheets` function. Why the `row` is always equal to zero in the for loop from the second arrow? It should enter `multiple_dfs` function and change the value of `row`. I tried to put at different place in the code, but it changed nothing. I don't have other idea anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change argument values like that.

```
 ...
   ...
  return len(df.index) + 2

 ...
   ...
    row = multiple_dfs(item, key, writer, row)
```